# How to inject multiple providers in app.config in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-providers

I have multiple providers in my project and each provider have its own constructor,I am trying to inject all these providers into main app.config.
I tried bellow scenario but its not working

tried to add all providers inside the array itself but its not working

```
app.config([
'EquityValueProvider', function (EquityValueProvider) {
EquityValueProvider.setAPIURL('https://localhost:44333/api/equityvalue');
},
'HeatMapServiceProvider', function (HeatMapServiceProvider) {
HeatMapServiceProvider.setAPIURL('https://localhost:44333/api/equityvalue');
},
'RetailerProvider', function (RetailerProvider) {
RetailerProvider.setAPIURL('https://localhost:44333/api/equityvalue');
}]);
```

but the bellow code is working (multiple config)

```
 app.config([
'EquityValueProvider', function (EquityValueProvider) {
EquityValueProvider.setAPIURL('https://localhost:44333/api/equityvalue');
 }])
.config([
'HeatMapServiceProvider', function (HeatMapServiceProvider) {
HeatMapServiceProvider.setAPIURL('https://localhost:44333/api/equityvalue');
}])
.config([
'RetailerProvider', function (RetailerProvider) {
RetailerProvider.setAPIURL('https://localhost:44333/api/equityvalue');
}]);
```

But here i am adding multiple config,instead of that can i make a single config and add all the providers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide three arguments to the config function:

```
app.config([
    'EquityValueProvider','HeatMapServiceProvider','RetailerProvider',   
    function (EquityValueProvider,HeatMapServiceProvider,RetailerProvider) {       
        EquityValueProvider.setAPIURL('https://localhost:44333/api/equityvalue');
        HeatMapServiceProvider.setAPIURL('https://localhost:44333/api/equityvalue');
        RetailerProvider.setAPIURL('https://localhost:44333/api/equityvalue');
    }
]);
```

For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Dependency Injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di).

Answer (score 1):

Here is how:

```
app.config([
'EquityValueProvider'
'HeatMapServiceProvider',
'RetailerProvider',
 function (EquityValueProvider, HeatMapServiceProvider, RetailerProvider) {
   EquityValueProvider.setAPIURL('https://localhost:44333/api/equityvalue');
   HeatMapServiceProvider.setAPIURL('https://localhost:44333/api/equityvalue');
   RetailerProvider.setAPIURL('https://localhost:44333/api/equityvalue');
}]);
```

You can add as many providers as you want.